# How to catch First-chance exception Js::JavascriptExceptionObject

Tags: javascript, c++, exception

We have a hybrid Windows app with a C++ core and JavaScript layer with an HTML front end.  On startup, I see a whole bunch of exceptions in the output window (of VS2013). Like this:

```
 First-chance exception at 0x756BC42D in SDKLauncher-Win.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptExceptionObject at memory location 0x0043D20C.
```

I see no additional info about the exception.  The exception appears to happen at the same address each time (in this case 0x756BC42D) but the memory object address is different. But when I examine that memory (0x756BC42D), there is not discernible code (at least not by the time I can pause the debugger and look).

However, I cannot seem to catch these exceptions to see what they are.  I am breaking in another instance of Visual Studio and turning on ALL JavaScript exceptions before they are thrown but neither instance of VS the native or JS ever catches the exceptions.

The app SEEMS to work OK despite these, but I don't like unexplained exceptions.

Any suggestions on how to catch these exceptions?

Comment: First chance exception messages do not mean there is a problem in the code: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx, you can ignore it until second chance exception is raised.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the feedback.  But it still bugs me...  :-)